# Custom Windows Taskbar Buttons

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I am wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for achieving a custom button that is added to the windows taskbar by my program.

I know it's possible to add a button to the top of a window (i have seen it done but don't know how it's done).

Edit:
I wish the button to inject into the taskbar itself, **not a tray icon**.

Comment: I have edited my question to include a mock up

Comment: I do not want a tray icon. I want an actual button to be injected into the taskbar

Comment: The area that you are pointing to in your illustration is the notification area.  Therefore I think that [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx) may prove to be a good starting point.

Comment: @DomSinclair The notification area is the same thing that people refer to as the tray. The screenshot points to the keyboard layout button and another button to the left of the notification area triangle as the desired button location.